# data lost in multithread

Tags: linux, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I use `pthread_create` to create many threads and in each thread, I use thread id as input to generate a name string `thread_<id>`, here is the problematic code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define THREAD_NUM 40

void *common_function(void *arg);

int main (void)
{
    int             res;
    unsigned int    i;
    pthread_t       t[THREAD_NUM];

    memset(t, 0x0, sizeof(t));

    for(i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++)
    {
        /* pass info */
        res = pthread_create(&(t[i]), NULL, common_function, (void *)&i);
        if(res !=0)
        {
            printf("thread: %d create fail\n", i);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<THREAD_NUM; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(t[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *common_function(void *arg)
{
    unsigned int    p;
#ifdef WRITE_FILE
    FILE            *fd;
    char            name[64];
#endif

    p = *(unsigned int *)arg;
#ifdef WRITE_FILE
    memset(name, 0x0, sizeof(name));
    sprintf(name, "thread_%02d", p);
    fd = fopen(name, "w");
    if(fd < 0 )
    {
        printf("create: %s fail\n", name);
        pthread_exit((void *)&p);
    }
#endif

#ifdef WRITE_FILE
    fprintf(fd, "%02d\n", p);
#else
    printf("thread: %02d\n",p);
#endif
    usleep(1);

#ifdef WRITE_FILE
    fclose(fd);
#endif

    pthread_exit((void *)&p);
}
```

I compiled the code use (I did not see any warning):

```
gcc -Wall -g -pthread -D_REENTRANT -DWRITE_FILE ./test_thread_problem.c
```

the output is:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_02
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_03
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_04
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_05
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_06
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_07
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_08
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_09
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_11
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_13
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_14
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_17
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_18
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_19
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_21
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_22
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_23
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_25
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_26
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_29
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_31
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_33
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_34
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_35
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_36
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_37
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_38
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haochen haochen    3  3月 13 08:56 thread_39
```

you could find there are some files missed, but it never print out the fail information after call `pthread_create` or `fopen`. I change to print only without create file (without `-DWRITE_FILE` option), also can see the problem:

```
./a.out
thread: 03
thread: 07
thread: 03
thread: 04
thread: 04
thread: 05
thread: 06
thread: 15
thread: 19
thread: 19
thread: 19
thread: 19
thread: 19
thread: 19
thread: 20
thread: 20
thread: 20
thread: 20
thread: 20
thread: 20
thread: 21
thread: 22
thread: 23
thread: 27
thread: 29
thread: 29
thread: 31
thread: 37
thread: 38
thread: 38
thread: 38
thread: 38
thread: 38
thread: 38
thread: 38
thread: 39
thread: 04
thread: 05
thread: 18
thread: 18
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I anticipate that you are aliasing i into the thread function. Every time you increment the value of I, it is getting impacted in the thread function.

Comment: What is actually happening is that when you pass address of `i` into the thread functions.. sometimes the thread may not have been launched yet. In that case, the loop increases i.. then the func gets called again.. by that time one or two threads have launched and both have the same address and same value at that instance in time.. I tried your code, sometimes it prints the same value 2-3 times. You can fix it by doing `int             id[THREAD_NUM];` then in the loop `id[i] = i;` and passing `&id[i]` as the thread arg..

Comment: @Brandon understood

Comment: @Brandon ome question, even I use a new variable, because I still let it equal to i, does it means there will be no racing condition any more? Why? Just because I stored them one by one in an array?

Comment: @HowChen; Not because you store it one by one in an array.. it's not a race condition simply because each thread is accessing a different address in the array and there is no concurrent modification of the array or that element. If two threads access (and/or modify) a variable (address) at the same time, it's MAY cause a race condition (usually one reading and one writing or both writing.. If both are reading, it's safe). In your case, the main thread was changing the variable `i`.. but your other threads were reading it.. That's a race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the same `i` as argument for all thread.

```
res = pthread_create(&(t[i]), NULL, common_function, (void *)&i);
                                                             ^^
```

That leads to race condition since main thread modifies `i` while all other threads read from `i`. I suggest you use different variable for each threads.

```
unsigned int    tid[THREAD_NUM];
...
for(i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
    /* pass info */
    tid[i] = i;
    res = pthread_create(&(t[i]), NULL, common_function, (void *)&tid[i]);
    ...
```